# C++ syntax with Nan::Utf8String

Tags: c++, node.js, node.js-addon

I'm working in a task to fix an node.js' addon write in C++, I don't known C++ but I can understand the general context.
Reading the code, the strech of code below, have not made sense to me:

```
Nan::Utf8String clientIP(clientIPV8.ToLocalChecked());
params["clientIP"] = *clientIP;
```

What means the clientIP?
What means *clientIP?

I didn't declare this "function" anywhere. The code has more than one occurrence equals this one, but the "function" name is changed. For example:

```
Nan::Utf8String clientPort(clientPortV8.ToLocalChecked());
params["clientPort"] = *clientPort;
```

- I don't known if this is a function.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clientIP` is a variable of type `Nan::Utf8String` initialized to `clientIPV8.ToLocalChecked()`

`*` is used to dereference a pointer variable, i.e. a variable containing the value of a memory address, so it should return whatever value `clientIP` is pointing to. But it can also be an overloaded `operator*`. All operators can be overloaded in C++, like any other function, and as mentioned in the comments, it is overloaded in this case to return a char* wrapped by `Nan::Utf8String`.

Comment: The `*` used to dereference a pointer variable is not correct in this context. It's an overloaded `operator*()` which returns `char *` in that case.

Comment: @Mansuro, this is a specific way to initialize a variable in C++?

Comment: @fhe, What does the `operator*()` do?

Comment: Guys, this is called constructor initialization and is a feature of C++.

Comment: @HumbertoCorrêa The `operator*()` most likely returns `const char*` in this case. I don't have access to the source code of `Nan::Utf8String`, but I guess it has some internal `char` buffer which is returned if you apply the `*` operator as in `*clientPort`. It's another way of accessing this data via a dedicated method call (which probably doesn't exist in this case).